# Relocate [region-locked] to [region-locking]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The [region-locked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/region-locked) tag is a past-tense verb. That doesn't make sense for a tag. I think it should be [region-locking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/region-locking) instead.

Comment: If we're going to do this, I'd favor 'lock' over 'locking. There's no reason to use a gerund.

Comment: Whilst I agree with @Less as to the wording, I'm wondering if its even a tag we need to have. Is it useful as a filter? Do experts have knowledge about regions and their lockiness? I feel we'd be better served removing it entirely. As for the few questions *only* tagged [region-locked], most are closed (or should be), and the rest could be retagged with the game/service in question.

Comment: [Data Explorer to the rescue!](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/163894/questions-with-a-single-tag?TagName=region-locked) As of this writing and the last data dump, there are 4 questions that are singularly tagged, and only ones is closed.  The other 3 are all from 2010, and while they probably still hold value, they would probably be considered off topic today.

Comment: If you really want to get technical, this is not in past tense; this is the past participle of the verb 'to region-lock'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, [region-lock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/region-lock) was created with [region-locked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/region-locked) as a synonym. I think that this is a better outcome.

We could still add [region-locking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/region-locking) as a synonym if desired.